# How to do a switch case or string format within an expression block

Tags: c#, switch-statement, string-formatting

How can I implement a switch case (or similar effect) in an expression body? I am creating a Model object (lets call it MyModel) and one of the fields is a recurrence field. The recurrence is based on the current day of the week (Monday's example is below). Basically I want to set the Weekly____ to be true. I was also thinking that potentially String.Format() would have something to support this, but I couldn't get it to work.

```
var my = new MyModel
{
    Recurrence = new RecurrenceModel
    {
        WeeklyMonday = true //what it would be on a Monday
    }
};
```

My attempt with switch case

```
var my = new MyModel
{
    switch(DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek.ToString())
        case "Monday":
            Recurrence = new RecurrenceModel
            {
                WeeklyMonday = true
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
};
```

My attempt with String.Format()

```
var my = new MyModel
{
    Recurrence = new RecurrenceModel
    {
        String.Format("Weekly{0}", DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek.ToString()) = true
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you're fairly new to C#?

What you need to do is something like this

```
var my = new MyModel
{
    Recurrence = new RecurrenceModel
    {
        WeeklyMonday = DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday
    }
};
```

In both of your attempts, you're not actually assigning the value to the property. Your code will not compile because it's not valid C#. You don't need a switch or a string.Format to achieve what you're after.

In my example, I'm assigning the result of `DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday` to the `WeeklyMonday` property on your model class

Comment: Yeah, fairly new to c#. I didn't even think to just put a simple statement for each day that would end up as true. Seems so obvious now to do it your way instead of trying to get Weekly____ to work.

Comment: It's ok, we all need to start somewhere :) I find that keeping things simple often makes things easier.

Answer (score 1):

simonlchilds is right. The best way to do this is within the constructor of the class, evaluating the value of the current day to set which property to true.

I personally would do something like this.

```
class RecurrenceModel
{
    public RecurrenceModel()
    {
        GetType().GetProperty("Weekly" + DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek).SetValue(this, true);
    }

    public bool WeeklyMonday { get; set; }
    public bool WeeklyTuesday { get; set; }
    public bool WeeklyWednesday { get; set; }
    public bool WeeklyThursday { get; set; }
    public bool WeeklyFriday { get; set; }
    public bool WeeklySaturday { get; set; }
    public bool WeeklySunday { get; set; }
}
```

That way, whenever this class is instantiated, it will automatically set whichever the day is to true and this is all you would need to do.

```
var my = new MyModel
{
    Recurrence = new RecurrenceModel()
};
```

Comment: I was going to suggest adding the logic to the constructor, but I'm on my phone and didn't want to type all that out! :D

Comment: While adding it in the way @Jun Kang did is very elegant, it won't work for my purposes. This isn't the only time/way RecurrenceModel is used so it can't be done with the constructor.